# simple confluent kafka spring boot app doesnt work, doesnt seem to be reading application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I created a confluent kafka broker via the confluent site, and created a topic via CLI.
Then I created a simple spring boot project via initializr with kafka lib.
Then created the simple producer and consumer class using the example code supplied by confluent:

https://github.com/johnvlittle/kafka1

However, it doesnt work.  It doesn't seem to be reading the application.properties file because it seems to be trying to connect to localhost instead of the bootstrap server:

```
2024-02-24T21:46:05.870+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2024-02-24T21:46:05.886+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [           main] o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.
2024-02-24T21:46:05.940+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : These configurations '[session.timeout.ms]' were supplied but are not used yet.
2024-02-24T21:46:05.941+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.6.1
2024-02-24T21:46:05.942+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 5e3c2b738d253ff5
2024-02-24T21:46:05.942+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1708807565941
2024-02-24T21:46:06.034+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-02-24T21:46:06.034+01:00  WARN 97874 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-02-24T21:46:06.035+01:00  WARN 97874 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-02-24T21:46:06.140+01:00  INFO 97874 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
```

The application.properties seem to be one problem:

```
# Required connection configs for Kafka producer, consumer, and admin
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers=pkc-xxx.eu-north-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='6IJSJXExxx' password='Fvfu4YcYhPJbULws0Usxxx';
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL

# Best practice for higher availability in Apache Kafka clients prior to 3.0
spring.kafka.properties.session.timeout.ms=45000
```

If I take the credentials and bootstrap server, and put them into "offset explorer app", I can connect to the kafka broker, and see the topic (with no messages yet).

spring.kafka.properties Dont seem to be documented, but I found an alternaive form for bootstrap server:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=pkc-xxx.eu-north-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
```

With this alternative form, the application works a bit more, but still fails to produce any message, and has this output from ./mvnw spring-boot:run

```
2024-02-24T22:17:31.587+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.6.1
2024-02-24T22:17:31.587+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 5e3c2b738d253ff5
2024-02-24T22:17:31.587+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1708809451587
2024-02-24T22:17:31.588+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [           main] fkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Subscribed to topic(s): bets
2024-02-24T22:17:32.207+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [ad | producer-1] com.ohds.kafka1.Producer                 : 

 Produced event to topic bets: key = key        value = value 


2024-02-24T22:17:32.268+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Cluster ID: lkc-219x1y
2024-02-24T22:17:32.269+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Discovered group coordinator b9-pkc-zm3p0.eu-north-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483638 rack: null)
2024-02-24T22:17:32.327+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2024-02-24T22:17:32.986+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id: consumer-springboot-group-1-1-f3f727a2-6ba0-4e97-8279-628ce8df8f35
2024-02-24T22:17:32.987+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Request joining group due to: rebalance failed due to 'The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.' (MemberIdRequiredException)
2024-02-24T22:17:32.988+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2024-02-24T22:17:33.057+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=3, memberId='consumer-springboot-group-1-1-f3f727a2-6ba0-4e97-8279-628ce8df8f35', protocol='range'}
2024-02-24T22:17:33.064+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Finished assignment for group at generation 3: {consumer-springboot-group-1-1-f3f727a2-6ba0-4e97-8279-628ce8df8f35=Assignment(partitions=[bets-0, bets-1, bets-2, bets-3, bets-4, bets-5])}
2024-02-24T22:17:33.136+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=3, memberId='consumer-springboot-group-1-1-f3f727a2-6ba0-4e97-8279-628ce8df8f35', protocol='range'}
2024-02-24T22:17:33.136+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[bets-0, bets-1, bets-2, bets-3, bets-4, bets-5])
2024-02-24T22:17:33.137+01:00  INFO 98914 --- [yConsumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-springboot-group-1-1, groupId=springboot-group-1] Adding newly assigned partitions: bets-0, bets-1, bets-2, bets-3, bets-4, bets-5
```

So it would appear that the application.properties keys for kafka are wrong, but they are the ones generated by confluent, and confluent is the company who created kafka, so they should know what they are doing?

I cant find the "correct" equivalent of the seemingly non working "properties" properties of:

```
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=xxx
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

Does anyone know the correct config keys?

Comment: The Spring docs show you need square brackets around attribute after `spring.kafka.properties` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: Interesting! the solution seems to be to delete the ".properties" part of the settings

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the application properties by removing the .properties part of the key.  It is stange that confluent would provide the wrong settings, but here is the working version of application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=pkc-xxx.eu-north-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
spring.kafka.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='6IJSJXxxx' password='Fvfu4YcYhPJbxxxx';
spring.kafka.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```